# Call outer method from run in TimerTask but doesn't refresh data

Tags: android

In Activity I have TimerTask which periodically executes and sometimes call function changeData ( changeData is function in Activity and put new text in text fileds ). Problem is that function changeData when is called doesn't refresh text fields, refresh when I scroll.
I tried with invalidate but doesn't help. Can anybody give me any suggestion ?

```
private void changeData(String text){
// TextView
txtSemi.setText(text);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The ui can only be updated by the UIThread. You can use a [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) inside your timer task.

This [blog](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html) has a pretty comprehensive tutorial. But basically, you just have to instantiate a Handler outside of your timer task and then, in the timer task you can do:

```
final String mytext = text;
    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                        txtSemi.setText(mytext);
                        }
                    });
```